# ORM performance cost

Tags: sql, database, performance, orm, frameworks

Does anyone have any experience that indicates what kind of performance hit a developer could expect by choosing to use an ORM (in Django, RoR, SQLAlechemy, etc) over SQL and hand-designed databases? I imagine there are complicating issues, including whether specifying a database within the constraints of an ORM increases or decreases the chances of creating an efficient database structure (based on the developer's level of experience), and the question of how well the developer constructs either the SQL or ORM-based queries (again based on his/her experience). Any information regarding these or intrinsic performance issues would be really interesting to me.

Comment: you could also not use one and use this: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Data%20access%20layer%20%28ORM%29%20with%20the%20Value%20Injecter&referringTitle=Home it's almost like an orm but you have full control over everything

Answer (score 33, accepted):

My advice is not to worry about this until you need to - don't optimise prematurely. An ORM can provide many benefits to development speed, code readability and can remove a lot of code repetition. I would recommend using one if it will make your application easier to develop.

As you progress through the development use benchmarks and profiling to determine the bottlenecks in the code and if needed you can bypass the ORM and use manual queries where they are required. Normally you will be able to improve the speed of the ORM using caching and database indexes (amongst other things) and then you can decide where manual queries are required. For the most part, the ORM performance will probably acceptable and the benefits of using it will far outweigh the performance cost.

Comment: yep, I agree with this.  The ORM may do something things nicely that you might not optimize with manual SQL without tweaking anyway.

Comment: Using IQueryables, Includes (eager loading), projections - will make your ORM (project) faster... For more I've included 2 more links in my direct answer to this post.

Answer (score 17):

Performance has always been an after thought in most DAL Layer development / architecture. I think its about time we start questioning the performance of these ORM tools, for the so-called ease of development they promise:

The 2 biggest areas of performance issues in ORMs are:

1. Inability to write Optimum SQL. You have to use an Object Query Language which is interpreted into SQL by the framework. Mostly it is good SQL, but often enough it is not the most efficient SQL.
2. Reflection. Most ORM frameworks use Reflection to populate objects with Data from the database. Reflection operations are costly, and with increasing number of load and data, the performance degradation becomes obvious.

Other performance issues that arise are because of inefficient Database Design or Entity Model design due to the tight coupling of Entity objects to Tables.

Answer (score 3):

It also depends on what you're using as an ORM. In my experience, Hibernate is a pig, in terms of speed, resource usage and startup time. LINQ to SQL, on the other hand, is an extremely light SQL wrapper, whose impact you'd likely barely (if at all) notice.

Comment: NHibernate is faster with identity columns than EF6.x is. And even comparable in speed with EF7. But EF6.x can be made really fast for read operations. See my direct answer in this forum too.

Answer (score -1):

**Performance** - its always pro and cons. If you deep deeper into ORM **architecture** (see my article: [avoid ORM bad habits](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/get-know-your-orm-avoid-bad-habits-balazs-hideghety)) then you will find intuitively the ways to make it faster. Here's my another article on how to make EF6x 5x **faster** (at least for read situations): [EF6.x 5x faster](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/orm-read-performance-ef-vs-dapper-balazs-hideghety)

**Anyhow for good performance, even with ORM you will need to create database views, indexes too as to check the queries that are generated and executed by ORM and fine tune them too. Eager loading is a must with ORM.**

Comment: These articles are too .NET specific to really be properly on topic here.

Comment: @Michael might be .NET specific, but the principle applies for every ORM - for reading you don't need to track the entity state and that helps to gain huge performance.