# Do Large High-Traffic Websites use ORMs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, orm

I have finally decided to go with the Entity Framework since it has the best performance out of all the ORMs. But before I start reading and writing code I just want to know if there are any high traffic websites out there that use ORMs.

Comment: I don't think that's true; have you looked at LLBLGen? How have you determined it has the best performance?

Comment: OH..I have just been doing alot of research online and looking at benchmarks. Everyone, online says that the entity frameworks outperforms any other ORM on .NET. Can you suggest an ORM that uotperfoms EF?

Comment: it doesn't answer which has best performance, but this is worth reading in relation to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/451845/orm-performance-cost

Comment: I raise my hand and call BS on any site that says "EF outperforms any other ORM".

Comment: Wow maybe I should have did some more research. I am interested in the LLBLGen. Is it efficient and can I put it in my DAL. Also, are there any good books on it?

Comment: I would be interested in how many servers these high traffic websites use because they are using an ORM.  If I have 10 servers for my website then performance may not be as big an issue, but, which ORM would be best to use for a high-traffic website using only one webserver.

Comment: Instead of a quest for "teh fastest ORM", just pick one that seems to be fairly well-regarded and lines up well with your needs, and start writing. I call BS on the ORM choice ending up being your bottleneck down the road.

Comment: Some definition of "High Traffic" web site might be useful.

Comment: Performance is relative, different ORMs perform differently based on the usage characteristics. Is the database big or small? How many joins/tables/relations? Do you have almost only SELECTs or do you have a significant amount of INSERTs or UPDATEs as well? A High Traffic News site will have different characteristics than a high traffic Forum/Collaboration site (BBC.co.uk != en.wikipedia.org), so I call BS on any flat "ORM X is the fastest" statement that isn't qualified with full benchmarks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Currently, the released version of EF, v1.0 in .NET 3.5, has terrible performance. I did extensive testing and had several long email discussions with Microsoft on the subject over a year ago when it was first released. EF's current efficiency has a LOT to be desired, and in many cases, can generate absolutely atrocious SQL queries that decimate your performance.

Entity Framework v4.0 in .NET 4.0 is a LOT better. They have fixed most, if not all, of the poor SQL generation issues that plague EF v1.0 (including the issues I presented to them a year ago.) Whether EF v4.0 has the best performance is really yet to be seen. It is more complex than LINQ to SQL, as it provides much greater flexibility. As a release version is not yet available, its impossible to say whether EF v4.0 will be the fastest or not.

An objective answer to this would require an objective, unbiased comparison between the major ORM contendors, such as EF, LINQ to SQL, nHibernate (preferably with a LINQ provider), LLBLGen, and even some of the newcommers, such as Telerik's ORM, Subsonic and the like.

As for large-scale, high-volume production systems that use ORM's. I would suggest looking at StackOverflow.com itself, which uses LINQ to SQL. SO has become one of, if not **the**, top programmer communities on the Internet. Definitely high volume here, and this site performs wonderfully. As for other sites, I couldn't really say. The internal implementation details of most major web applications are generally a mystery. Most uses of ORM's that I know of are also for internal, enterprise systems. Financial systems, health care, etc. Object Databases are also used in the same kinds of systems, although they are much less frequent. I would so some searches for ORM use and high volume web sites.

One thing to note in your search. Make sure the reviews you find are current. The ORM scene has changed a LOT in the last two years. Performance, efficiency, capabilities, RDBMS tuning capability of dynamic SQL, etc. have all improved significantly since ORM's were first created around a decade ago.

Comment: That's strange, my experience of the EF was it produced very optimised queries especially with joins, compared to NHibernate atleast.

Comment: If I could dig them up, I have several threads on the old msdn EF forum that demonstrate some of the truly atrocious SQL generation that EF v1.0 had. I compared the generated SQL from L2S to that of EF, and not only was the SQL a monstrosity of several levels of nested selects, joins on null, and other oddball crud...it performed about 10 ORDERS OF MAGNITUDE worse than the L2S query. In one case, I was trying to select 90 records from a join on a couple hundred. The EF query joined in such a way that SQL Server had to filter through 50 BILLION virtual rows internally.

Answer (score 6):

I know in one of the podcasts, Jeff mentioned that stackoverflow uses Linq-to-SQL

Answer (score 6):

The *really* high traffic websites are in fact moving away from SQL databases altogether because with write-heavy workloads common in today's apps, it's nearly impossible to make them scale beyond one machine, ORM or no ORM. This has been dubbed the "[NoSQL movement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nosql)"

However, while this is a very fashionable topic, it's [completely irrelevant](http://www.eflorenzano.com/blog/post/my-thoughts-nosql/) for sites that don't have thousands of active concurrent users. And worrying about ORM performance is a similar matter: most sites are not in fact "high traffic" enough for an ORM to become a problem (unless grossly misimplemented or -applied).

Answer (score 4):

While not directly addressing which ORM is faster as [Ayende](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/08/21/how-to-lose-respect-and-annoy-people.aspx) (NHibernate author) points out can be very easy to do wrong or at least slant the way you want it to, here are apps out there that are using ORMS as part of their applications.

Twitter is (was?) using Ruby on Rails (RoR) which uses an ORM.  The [37 signal](http://37signals.com/) guys use RoR for their apps ....  I know these aren't .Net but as mentioned by kuoson, L2S is employed by SO and there are alot of people out there using NHibernate like [Jeffrey Palermo](http://jeffreypalermo.com/) and Headspring.  I wouldn't be surprised to find many recently developed web apps are employing an ORM.

Even if an ORM does cost you a hit on performance, most ORM's allow you to customize the SQL used when necessary.  Most suggest using the ORM and then fixing bottlenecks as they arise.  Additionally, a good ORM solves so much for you that writing your own DAL is becoming a much tougher sell these days.

Comment: Twitter switched away from RoR for their backend processing, mainly for performance reasons.

Comment: True, but that doesn't mean ORMs can't perform.  :)

Answer (score 4):

jrista is right on. I just want to add that you should seriously consider LINQ to SQL. From both a simplicity and a performance standpoint it is the better technology (for now). It is very fast and reasonably capable out-of-the-box. If you want to further improve LINQ to SQL, check out the [PLINQO framework](http://plinqo.com/).

PLINQO is a framework that sits around standard LINQ to SQL and adds a ton of features including some very elegant bulk operations and caching features. Best of all PLINQO adapts to changes in your database schema but preserves your custom code. Which is VERY slick and, in my opinion, the most valuable aspect.

Comment: PLINQO is not free and LinqToSql has a lot of problems.  Subsonic provides great simplicity for free.  NHibernate scales for free.

Comment: Yeah, PLINQO is free. Codesmith isn't, if that's what you mean

Answer (score 2):

Sure, reddit uses parts of SQLAlchemy (for reasons unknown I believe they rewrote most it :/).  Most, if not all of the large Django websites use the ORM (including the former Pownce and Curse).