# Is entity framework a bad choice for multiple websites and large aplications?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, performance, sql-server-2005, entity-framework-4

**Scenario** : We currently have a website and are working on building couple of websites with an admin website. We are using asp.net-mvc , SQL Server 2005 and Entity Framework 4. So, currently we have a single solution that has all the websites and all the websites are using the same entity framework model. The Model currently has over 70 tables and will potentially have a lot more in the future... around 400?

**Questions** : Is Entity Framework model going to be slower when it is going to grow bigger? I have read quite a few articles where they say it is pretty slow due to the additional layers of mapping when as compared to say ado.net? Also , we thought of having multiple models but it seems that it is a bad practice too and is LINQ useful when we are not using any ORM?

So, we are just curious what and how all the large websites using a similiar technology as we have achieve good performance while using an ORM like EF or do they never opt for an ORM ? I have also worked on a LINQ to SQL application that had over 150 tables and we encurred a huge startup penalty, site took 15-20 seconds to respond when first loaded. I am pretty sure this was due to large startup cost of LINQ to SQL ORM. It would be great if someone can share their experience and thoughts regarding this ? What are the best practices to follow and I know it depends on every application but if performance is a concern then what are the best steps to be taken ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't have a definite answer for you, but I have found this SO post: [ORM performance cost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451845/orm-performance-cost), it will probably be informative for you, expecially the second highest answer mentioning this site:

http://ormbattle.net/

My personal experience is that for any ORM mapper I have seen so far, Joel's [law of leaky abstraction](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html) applies heavily. So if you are going to use EF, make sure you have alternatives for optimization at hand.

Comment: ormbattle.net has a bad reputation as it was started by a single commerical ORM vendor for marketing purposes without working very cooperatively with other ORM vendors.  The performance tests are not necessarily representative of real life ORM usage scenarios and should be taken with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can certainly get EF4 to work in a performant way with a database with a large number of tables.  That said, you will certainly have to overcome a number of hurdles that are specific to EF.

I don't think LinqToSql is a good alternative since Microsoft has stopped enhancing it for the most part.

What other alternatives have you considered?  ADO.NET?  NHibernate?  Stored Procedures?

I know NHibernate may have trouble establishing the SessionFactory for 400 tables quickly, but that only happens once when the website application starts, which should be fairly rare if the application is used heavily.  Each web request generally has a new Session and creating sessions from the session factory is very quick and inexpensive.

Answer (score -1):

My biggest concern with EF is the management of the thing, if you have multiple models, then you're suddenly going to have multiple work to do maintaining them, making sure you never update the wrong model for the right database, or vice versa. This is a problem for us at the moment, and looks to only get worse.

Personally, I like to write SQL rather than rely on an abstraction on top of an abstration. The DB knows SQL and so I keep it happy with hand-crafted stored procedures, or hand-crafted SQL in some cases. One huge benefit to this is that I can reply code to see what it was trying to do, and see the resulting data by c&p the sql from the log to the sql query editor. That, in my opinion, makes support so much easier it entirely invalidates any programmer benefit you might have from using an ORM in the first place (especially as EF generates absolutely unreadable SQL).

In fact, come to think of it, the only benefit an ORM gives you is that you can code a bit quicker (once you have everything set up and are not changing the schema, of course), and ultimately, I don't think the benefit is worth the cost, not when you consider that I spend most of my coding time thinking about what I'm going to do as the 'doing it' part is relatively small cmpared to the design, test, support and maintain parts.

Comment: This is a terrible answer.  "Bit quicker" lol.  I'm not sure what you are doing but if your EF productivity gains is only a "bit quicker" than writing 4 stored procs for every entity your doing something wrong.   - Your quip about management is pretty meaningless too because you'd end up changing all of your CRUD procs anyway.

Comment: @jfar - Agreed, -1 from me as well. Another development speed benefit from using EF is the ability to easily replace the SQL database with an in-memory backing store that uses LINQ-to-objects for unit testing purposes, allowing you to test your queries as well rather than mocking them away. How will I catch a `GetPaymentAmount` doing `COUNT` instead of a `SUM` with a SP? Sure, by *doing more work and writing additional tests*. No thanks.

Comment: maybe management issues is more to do with the multiple models we have to maintain, but @JulianR - you're really saying that its easier to mock away the DB entirely, than it is to replace the SP accessor with one that returns expected results? You can test the SP separately you know, its a very nice division or work to do.

Comment: It *is* easier, much easier. You simply create a `Dictionary<Type, List<object>>` and that's your "database" which you fill with unit test data. There's no need to create additional tests for your SPs (and besides, I don't want tests that rely on database access), you get testing of your queries essentially for free because when using EF it doesn't matter whether you're querying against a SQL database or a `Dictionary`.